# Horizontal Overflow Issue with CSS Sticky Footer

Tags: css, sticky-footer

Take a look at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ and resize your browser window to < 600px.

Notice how the header and footer elements fall short as the content overflows beyond their width.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening so that when the page scrolls horizontally, the header and footer don't fall short?

[image]

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean by fall short? Do you mean that they stop once they hit a minimum width?

Comment: Is there a reason `width:100%;` is not declared?

Comment: @Liam: I added a screenshot of what I believe is the problem.

Comment: I can't see the problem in FF4 or Chrome.  Did you fix it? Or maybe another browser?

Comment: stick everything inside another wrapper might work

Comment: I don't know if it would as the content isn't the issue here.  It remains the correct width.  It's that the header and footer are sizing to the viewport, as opposed to the document width.

Comment: I've tried assigning min-width: 960px as a test, seems to be working. Can anyone see any flaws in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be solved by assigning a *min-width* to the elements that are not stretching along with the rest of the document.

In a DOM inspector on the example site, try adding:

```
min-width: 960px;
```

...to the header and footer.  Problem solved!  I've used this quite a few times with good results across all browsers and devices.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is a side effect of making the window more narrow than .main, .foot, and the other layout elements with static width. If they had no widths, or smaller widths, it works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

No one actually users a browser with less than 600px width. Even 800x600px is dying with most people, take a look on this survey results: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp

You should only worry with horizontal overflow and other problems for smaller page widths for mobile devices, in this case, a proper mobile browser and specific stylesheets will solve the deal.

Comment: Monitor resolution is not a great indicator of how much real estate is available in the browser.  Even though my monitor is 1680px wide, I don't use my browser full screen.

Comment: I prefer to not make any assumptions.  I know of some situations where as KatieK indicates, people use their browsers smaller than the full width of the site.  There are perfectly acceptable reasons to be interested in this.  If at the very least to ensure a good, stable layout.

Comment: I based my comment on real statistical and usage data. According to W3C the 640x800px resolution is already gone for 99.99% of the web. A lot of people still uses 800x600px resolution, but most of them navigate with more than 600px wide screen. Fact.